# joomla 3.6 admin language won't change

Tags: joomla-3.x, language, administration

http://www.weiwei-tv.com/scroll.php

As the video shows, I go to language->installed->administration and change the default language to en-US, although the message is in English, the menu items won't change back to English.

Then I clear Joomla's cache, change to a new browser, although the login page is in English, the back-end menu items are still not. I just began to manage this website which is built by other and I never had any trouble switching languages on my own sites.

What is wrong?

Comment: At the login page, you can either choose the language, or your account is set to the English language and not to the default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you've set the default admin language for your own user. Alter this setting for your user by going to your site's administration and go to users > manage > choose your user > basic settings tab > backend language.

Comment: would you be more specified on how to check user details and where to change.

Comment: Added the steps to get to where to change the settings